# oil spots on Air Filter

Tags: chevrolet, air-filter, pcv-valve

I have Matiz 1.0 with 122K Km on the meter. Today i noticed oil on air filter
[image]
after inspection i found this might be coming from PCV hose(green highlighted one) 
[image]
and then inspected the PCV valve.
[image]

this valve by definition is one way, but when i blew into the valve it was open from both sides. Is my PCV valve is faulty or there is something else need to check for oil on air filter.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that the valve you have pictured is the PCV valve. A PCV valve traditionally is a connection between the intake manifold and the crank case. The line pictured, from the crank case to the air filter, is most likely a fresh air intake or breather line. But i think your on the right track to look for the PCV valve. A poorly working PCV system can cause oil spots on the air filter.

When you find the PCV valve it should have a spring and plunger inside. 
[image: PCV valve internal operation]

If you shake the valve (removed from car) it should rattle. When it's disconnected fro the crank case side only and the engine is running, placing your thumb over the valve and removing it should cause a very noticeable clicking sound.

Comment: this actually a PCV valve and evident from http://s56.radikal.ru/i153/1001/2b/7d08b3cbd2c6.jpg , can you confirm that a pcv valve shoud blow air from both sides or from single side?

Comment: Just from one side but it's not a perfect one way valve, you'll have some flow in both directions but way more one way. The rattling i mentioned earlier is more important. All of this does not negate the fact that a PCV valve should be between the intake manifold and crank case.

Comment: i checked it has rattling sound and same it has a spring as well